# paypal api - how to implment monthly subscription + varying extra charges each month

Tags: paypal, recurring

I am developing a website in .net .

I have two requirements as follows:

1. in the application , customer pays monthly for publishing advertisement and that fee is fixed.
2. the customer needs to pay the amount for total click on that advertisement at the end of the month.
3. both payment need to be automated once the customer registered with the site and does first payment.

I have implemented the first requirement using payflow api and it works properly .
but I dont how to implment second requirement .

could any one has faced this problem and how can it be solved?(i dont store the customer payment details (like creditcard or paypal details in our site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#submitting-reference-transactions---tokenization) to process the variable amount each month.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I read that it expires after 12 month .in this case I would like to know, when we do a recurring payment with a fixed amount, does paypal generate new transaction number for each month? if yes , Is there any way to get the latest transaction number so that i will keep on use latest transaction number ?

Comment: Yes, there will be a new transaction number generated when recurring payments occur, however, I have never specifically tested if those transactions are compatible with a reference transaction.  You'll want to test that in the sandbox.

Comment: one more thing that  i would like to know is that the reference transaction can be used with paypal login also. i have kept two option for payment credit cards or paypal account? i was just wondering how can it be done since it should work without login details.

Comment: Yes, you would do that with Express Checkout.  In your SetExpressCheckout request (which starts the process) you would include parameters to setup a billing agreement.  Then you can use the transaction ID you get back from that original Express Checkout transaction in the DoReferenceTransaction API to process future payments.